# Can't import azure pusblish settings certificates reliable into windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, x509certificate, windows-phone-8.1

I want to work with the azure rest service on my windows phone 8.1 but i hit a wall while trying to import the access certificate from the .publishsettings-file into the app certificate store.

As far as i can tell the only way to import the encoded x.509-certificate from file on windows phone 8.1 (due to non-availability of the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates-Namespace) is to use this method here

```
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(string, 
    string,
    ExportOption,
    KeyProtectionLevel, 
    InstallOptions, 
    string);
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificateenrollmentmanager.importpfxdataasync)

My issue is that this method seems highly unreliable on windows phone 8.1! Sometimes i can find the certificate after import, usually i can't. It gets worse when i try to add a second or third certificate to the cert store.

Funny enough, after a restart of the app i sometimes can find the imported certificate from the last session which i could not find in the session.

I tried on different devices to exclude hardware as a cause.

The same code runs fine on a windows 8.1 store-app, certificates from publish settings can always be found after import with this method.

I uploaded a sample VS2013 solution with a project for a windows phone 8.1 app as well as a project for a windows 8.1 store-app. Just run the app, click the add-publish.settings-button, download your .publishsettings-file and open it with the app to reproduce the issue. (To remove the certs, just uninstall the app). The executed code is copy-paste, no difference. It can be found [in my dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nzswz7emq1hvcj3/AACeF--Cfh2VmR4rEziZO47Qa)

Has anyone an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a faulty implementation in the windows phone 8.1 release.
The latest updated fixed the issue.